# norwegian character wrongly displayed web sphere

Tags: html, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a login page where we have included a java script file having some norwegian characters.After building the code and deploying the code in websphere ,norwegians character are wrongly dispalyed like  pÃ¥ .I have set the content type in login.jsp as UTF-8 ,also tried with ISO-8859-1

Also my encoding type in eclipse is ISO-8859-1 .I Also tried with UTF-8.

When i try to edit and just update my js in directory where it is installed ,it works.I just have to add space and save it.

Comment: Please provide [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Are your files also formatted to UTF-8? By default programs like notepad++ and filezilla makes the file encoded in ANSI.

Another solution could be adding "AddDefaultCharset utf-8" to your .htaccess file.

Comment: yes all the html files are UTF-8 formatted and pageEncoding is also set as UTF-8. I am accessing the application directly from application server i.e i dont have web server in place.